# how can i change background of items which are in v-for loop vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I have this array

```
      items: [
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
        },
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
        },
]
```

I want to give each of these items specific background, how can I do this?

here my `v-for` loop code:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div :style="whatShouldIGiveItHere">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I've tried to add the variant backgrounds color with this `computed` but it doesn't work :

```
colorVariant() {
  const colorVar = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
  colorVar.forEach((val) => {
    return val
  })
},


<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div :style="background:colorVariant">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define th colors array then use the index to get a color :

```
data(){
  return {
 colors : ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
  items: [
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
          bgColor: 'red',

        },
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
          bgColor: 'green',
        },
]

}

}
```

in template :

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div :style="{'background-color':colors[index]}">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a different background-color for each card, you can add a property inside your items array.

```
items: [
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
          bgColor: 'red',

        },
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
          bgColor: 'green',
        },
]
```

While looping add a style like this

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div :style="`background-color: ${item.bgColor}`">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

// Edit - Need the background color outside of the items array ( not a good way though )

```
bgColors: ['red', 'green'],
items: [
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
        },
        {
          cardTitle: 'Mathew Slick attached 2 files',
          dateTime: '15 min ago',
          contentTitle: 'Article / Post',
          contentValue:
            'The history of video game is as interesting as a fairy tale. The quality of today’s video game was not at all there when',
        },
]
```

```
/* the loop will take the same index color and add it to the card. */
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div :style="`background-color: ${bgColors[index]}`">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't wanna add bgColor on array , I want to inject it from outside of the array

Comment: So you want to have the same background-color on every card ?

Comment: No, as is said in question , I want to give each of these items specific background